# How to change value of datagridview?

Tags: c#, datagridview

I have a `DataGridView` where I show some values and has a column with name `status`. This column `status` has values 1 or 0 and I want to change this to `Active` when is 1 and `Inactive` when is 0.

How could I do this ?

Trying.

```
int i = gridUsuarios.Columns["status"].Index;
            if (gridUsuarios.Rows[i].Cells[i].Value == "1") {
                gridUsuarios.Rows[i].Cells[i].Value = "Active";
            }else {
                gridUsuarios.Rows[i].Cells[i].Value = "Inactive";
            }
```

Comment: How you bind your `DataGridView`?

Comment: @Alex Yes, it is !

Comment: If the DGV is databound you will probably need to manipulate the datasource. I would create a computed column there and display it instead of the numeric one. This way you don't destroy the numeric data.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This can be done using DataGridCellFormatting event. A sample snippet is as follws:

```
private void gridUsuarios_CellFormatting(object sender,System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewCellFormattingEventArgs e)
{
    if (this.gridUsuarios.Columns[e.ColumnIndex].Name == "status")
    {
        if (e.Value != null)
        {
            e.Value.ToString() == "1" ? e.Value = "Active" : e.Value = "Inactive";
            e.FormattingApplied = true;
        }
    }
}
```

Documentation on [DataGridView.CellFormatting event is here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridview.cellformatting.aspx).